# How do I remove Windows Mixed reality apps / demos etc

Tags: windows-10-v1709

I am running Windows 10 v1709 and experimenting with a Lenovo Explorer Windows Mixed Reality VR headset.

I have installed various demos, apps and so on from within the "Cliff House" VR interface.

However these apps do not show in Programs and Features in Windows.

Where can I access and uninstall them?

Answer (score 1):

I have to deploy images of WIN10 Pro where I work, WIN10 is a beast and difficult to configure without the changed configuration reverting back after updates.
If you don't know about PSEX and SQL-Lite, I would suggest you do not try this.
You have to find PSEX and SQL-Lite and download them and put them in a folder to do this. Works 100%. First you have to uninstall the Mixed Reality Portal.

Downloads:

http://sqlitebrowser.org/    (SQL-Lite)

https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx  (PSEX) Yep, in foreign language, but only way I could get it, MS hiding it in English.

Remove Mixed Reality Portal (You must know how to open registry and use it. Search for 'regedit', and open)

- Regedit and change FirstRunSucceeded to 1 @ HKeyCurrentUser\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Holographic
- I've never seen it NOT there, if it is not, create the DWORD-32 value FirstRunSucceeded
- Close registry
- Open WIN10 Settings and then open Mixed Reality, and select "Uninstall" (may have to restart)

When you open settings now, the Reality Portal should be gone, but the Portal remains in the Start Menu.

Place the PSEX files (extract them) and SQL-Lite install file in a folder in the root of C:, I used C:\WIN10. You should have 28 files (29 if you keep the PSEX downloaded file)

(You must know Powershell, search for Powershell, right-click on top search result and Run as Administrator)

Run Powershell command 'Get-AppxPackage | Select name, PackageFullName' and leave screen open to match apps for removal (Note - You cannot do this command while editing with SQL-Lite) This command will list the Package Name of all apps installed.

- Open Command Prompt, browse to folder with PSEX (You must know how to browse in Command Prompt - cd.. goes up a directory, cd 'name of folder' goes to folder named, etc.)
- Type: psexec.exe -i -s -d cmd.exe and hit enter <--new window opens up
- In new Command Prompt browse to the folder with SQL-Lite and type in the install file name (mine is SQL-Lite.exe) and press enter, choose option to open and install to c:\SQL-Lite <--Make sure to install there or know where it is!
- Once SQL-Lite opens (or open it from where you installed it), click "Open Database," browse to C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository
- Open StateRepository-Machine.srd <--choose "show all files"
- Click "Browse Data" tab, in the drop down box select "Package"
- Scroll right to the "PackageFullName" column <--widen the window and the "PackageFullName" column to see the entire name
- Change "Inbox" to "0" for HolographicFirstRun (has a lot of other info on the line FYI, and anything with holographic change the inbox - 0 allows uninstall/removal)(same goes for anything else you want to remove. If it is important, WIN10 will not allow you to remove it)
- Once done, save the database. Click on "write changes" then close from file menu
- You must use the Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers *name* | Remove-AppxPackage to finish removing from the StartMenu

!!IMPORTANT!! Super user does not allow me to add asterisks, it just formats the word to italic. So the word "name" in the command is (asterisk)name(asterisk)

Here is the command you want Digital Lightcraft:

Get-AppxPackage (asterisk)holographic(asterisk) | Remove-AppxPackage

The asterisks are actually wild cards, so if you type in (asterisk)viewer(asterisk)' it will remove any app that has that word in it. In your case it is HolographicFirstRun, but why type all of that?

When that is ran, you will see teal blue code run, which means it is working. Anything in red means it failed.

It should be gone from the Start Menu now.

- NOTE - Get-AppxPackage does not work for all users, especially Holographic First Run, so you may have to do this for each user.

I spent 3 months on WIN10 at work, I know it pretty well. If you do understand this do not be intimidated by the steps, I was when I got the original steps to do this, now I made them easy to follow and documented step by step while I did them. Follow the steps exactly.

Anyone who sees this and it works, please jack me up on points I spent a lot of time on this, a LOT OF TIME. Thanks MS, like I needed to do all of this to deploy a PC at work.

You will feel a great sense of power over Microsoft after doing this, and after a few updates, the Mixed Reality Portal remains removed....for now.

MANY THANKS TO THE FINDER - Basics.net <--they rock.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this answer except for the fact you needlessly call me out.  So I just flagged it for a moderator to handle.  If you had not called me out, I might have been nice enough, to properly format your answer for you.

Comment: No idea what PSEX is exactly but here is an English download of psExec is what you linked to: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec

Comment: I'm OK with that. I hope the moderator see's you say something about everyone of my posts when I am just trying to help other people or ask a question. And if I get banned, fine, I won't waste time helping people with my expertise. And you do this to everyone.

Comment: If I have made a comment against every one of your answers it’s because they were in the review queue.  If your not willing to remove the comment about me so be it, I could personally careless.

Comment: That's fine. Whatever. I am going to go delete my account just so I don't have to see any of your comments again. Enjoy yourself.

Comment: I am sorry I hear you will be deleting your account.

Comment: ......... wow. Errm, well thanks to the mysterious poster, but I wasn't asking how to remove the Remove Mixed Reality Portal anyway!!

Answer (score -2):

On the HoloLens go to the desired app that you want to uninstall (Bloom gesture --> +sign and navigate to the app) air tap and hold. This will give you two options. One for Pin and the other to Uninstall.

From https://forums.hololens.com/discussion/1223/uninstall-app

Comment: A: This isnt HoloLens, this is WMR.
B: I installed various demos and apps, I have no idea what they are called, I want a list, as most dont show in control panel/ programs and features.